# Thymeleaf with OpenLayers 4

Tags: html, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf, openlayers

I have this piece of code in a template :

```
 view: new ol.View({
                               center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([/*[[${center.longitude}]]*/, /*[[${center.latitude}]]*/]),
                           zoom: 14
                         })
```

this is the value of the object:

```
center [ Coordinate [latitude=41.33434906005859, longitude=1.8457042932510377]]
```

but when I see the source of the template I see this

```
view: new ol.View({
                               center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([[[${center.longitude}]], /*41.33434906005859*/]),
                           zoom: 14
                         })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please assign the values into js variables first.

```
var centerLat = /*[[${center.longitude}]]*/;
var centerLng = /*[[${center.latitude}]]*/;
```

Then use it.

```
 view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([centerLng, centerLat]),
        zoom: 5
    })
```

Find the working code in [here](https://gitlab.com/supun/spring-boot-app/commit/332f28df48568fe22a88a78b5dbfb88e95ef6f65)